# Unable to override existing CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using the example mentioned [here](http://evan.dojotoolkit.org/dojo-1.7rc1-gridx/gridx/tests/test_grid.html) in my project. I want to stretch the table to fit the whole page.

So, I did:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

#gridContainer {
    height: 100%;
}

table{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The problem is, only the table header appears on the page and it is stretched properly. The rows do not show up. I also tried to place the `<script>` before the `<style>`, but no luck.

How do I fix this?

Comment: A link is not sufficient for a problem description. Include, in the question itself, HTML and CSS (preferably, minimal) that actually reproduce the problem.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela The link is not about the problem. It is an example of what I am using at my end.

Answer (score 0):

Make the below change.

```
table, div {
   width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. check the updated one. - @RahulDesai

Comment: The table rows still do not show up. The header is stretched.

Comment: Clear cache and check it again. It works for me. - @RahulDesai

Comment: Use `width: 100% !important;` to reflect the change. - @RahulDesai

Comment: have you used `width: 100% !important;` ?? - @RahulDesai

Comment: Yes, I did. But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
.dojoxGridxBody, .gridContainer, table, #gridContainer {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

If you want to make no other changes you will have to use `!important` to override some of the original CSS.  But you can use the chrome inspector to find out what this style is overriding, remove the widths that would be set without this in the old CSS and then remove the `!important`

This page is far from ideally laid out however, as when you change the column structure the page just gets wider and wider.  You have multiple tables and divs within these when actually you only need one table.

Comment: Sorry, this isnt making any change.

Comment: Works fine for me on your site.  Have you cleared your cache?